# Error: HTTP Error 400/Deployment error. Build Failed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a cloud function and am getting hit with these errors. `Error: HTTP Error 400`, `Deployment error. Build Failed`.

After searching around, I now know that the issue is with the path.

However, I am really not sure how to rewrite it. I just keep getting errors

```
exports.createContact = functions.region('europe-west2').firestore
.document('?')
.onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
```

The path on Firestore

/userData/at5GWYhP1HaOzhbizA3adsbw6vX2/Contacts/6FgyTkzs2z8DAaONCEam

Comment: I can't find it now, but I saw a question just a few days ago from someone that had a similar issue deploying to 'europe-west2'. Have you tried using a different region? Also, `'?'` isn't the actual string you're using for the `.document`, is it? It needs to be the path to the document(s) you want to use as a trigger.

Comment: Furthering the previous: Firestore triggers do not accept wildcards - you can trigger on specific documents, or collections, but NOT wildcards.

Comment: @nVitius Interesting, I would test for different regions but I'm not even sure on the correct path to use. And yes, `?` is just a placeholder

Comment: @LeadDreamer Okay, that makes sense. So if I used the path I specified, how would it be best written?

Comment: @LeadDreamer You can definitely use wildcards for Firestore Triggers. You can use them for both collection names and document IDs [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the questions that came up in the comments:
You can see all the regions supported by cloud functions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations

For your document path, you will need to do this:
`userData/{userId}/Contacts/{contactId}`
That will match any contact made under any user. You can read more on Firestore triggers here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

Comment: Thank you. I also changed my node version to 12 and removed the region. They deployed perfectly.